# Can multiple threads of the same process run on different processors in a multiprocessor system?

Tags: multithreading

Threads of the same process can run on different cores on a multicore processor . Suppose we have a multiprocessor system (not multicore) . Can two threads of the same process run on different processors at the same time ?

Answer (score 5):

The true answer depends on what operating system you are running on the hardware, and it depends on how that operating system is configured.

Out of the box, most operating systems *will* schedule different threads of the same process on different processors.  Google for "processor affinity" for how you might change that.

The fact that different threads can be scheduled on different processors is the root of the whole *memory visibility* issue.  If all threads of a single process were "pinned" to the same processor, then *visibility* would not be a problem.

Comment: Do the threads in that case still share the same memory, as they do if they are all executed only on a single processor?

Comment: @user2340939, Going by the modern, and most widely accepted definitions of the words, all of the _threads_ in the same _process_ share the same virtual address space—all the same variables. In modern usage, a process is a "container" for things associated with an instance of some application including its virtual memory space, its open files, its network connections, its windows, ..., and one or more threads of execution.